# How to toggle value in database on click of a button (YII2)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

I've got some data with one of the fields called activity. Activity can be either 0 (inactive) or 1 (active) in the database.

I have the delete button next to each row of data in my index page and would like that, when it is clicked, if activity is set to 1, i would like it to be set to 0.

So basically the delete does not delete anything, it just switches the activity value from 1 to 0. I have some code also which checks if activity is already set to 0 and prevents from further deletion.

How can I do this pls?

This is the code in my controller;

```
    public function actionDelete1($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();
   

    return $this->redirect(['index']);

}



public function actionRetire($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->activity = 0;
    $model->save();
    
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

This is the code in my model:

```
 public function canRetire($id)
{
   if(!$this->checkIfRetired($id)
    return true;
   else return false;
}

public function checkIfRetired($id)
{
    if(JobPlanning::find()->where([ 'and', 'activity=:activity AND 
    id=:id'],array(':activity'=>1,':id'=>$id))->count() >0) 
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

And the delete button in my index page:

```
'delete' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                        return $model->canRetire($model['id'])?Html::a(Html::tag('span', '', ['class' => "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"]), $url, ['title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'), 'data' => ['method' => 'post', 'confirm' => Yii::t('app', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'), 'params' => ['id' => $model['id'], '_csrf' => Yii::$app->request->csrfToken]]]):'';

if ($action === 'delete') {
                         $url = 'index.php?r=admin/jobplanning/retire&id=' . $model['id'];
                        return $url;
                    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't `update your-table set activity=0 where id=:id` do it for you? I'm not sure if there's much point checking whether it's already marked inactive - why would it matter if a user was to somehow mark an already-inactive user as inactive again? Unless it's doing other things as part of the process, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a soft delete then: no actual row is deleted but "marked". Two parts for this code:

Controller

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        // ....
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],
        // ....
    ];
}


public function actionDelete($id){
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->activity = 0;
    if(!$model->save()){
        //throw exception
    }
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}
```

the button

```
'delete' => function($url, $model, $key){
    return $model->activity == 1
        ? Html::a('DELETE ICON', $url, ['data-method' => 'post', 'data-confirm' => 'are you sure...'])
        : "";
}
```

Note I have defined the action as just accesible when called with POST method because this is going to change the state of data. You can force a POST link with the `data-method => 'post'` passed to the `options` parameter of the `Html::a()` helper function.

To totally prevent deletion via ActiveRecord operations override `beforeDelete` on the model class:

```
public function beforeDetete(){
     return false;
}
```

I think you don't need extra methods.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try the following code? And then edit your code in the view part as required to call the api.

```
public function actionRetire($id, $status)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    //$model->activity = !$model->activity;
    $model->activity = !$status;
    if($model->save())
    \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'Succesfully updated);


    
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

PS: Since you dont want to disable the toggle, its better to pass the status from the view through the request, there by making it stateless. I have updated the code to do that.

Comment: This is for if you want to simply toggle the data. You can sanitize the $id or check for exception handling as per your use case.

Comment: what happens if this action is called again? it will toggle the activity attribute. Perhaps the name of the action in the example could be improved.

Comment: the code in my answer is updated. this is just a soft delete. Instead of delete, set a field marking this instance is not usable anymore: in this case activity. There is no way to restore it. Perhaps the instances with activity == 0 should not be listed anymore. Anyway, via controller is not possible to delete this model. Other check could be done in `beforeDelete()` of the class: return false. This makes impossible to delete it via ActiveRecord operations.